# How can two view models communicate using catel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, catel

I read the documentation how can communicate with view models and I try it. But is can't changed. Like the examples from github I create CommunicationViewModel:

```
public abstract class CommunicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CommunicationViewModel()
    {
        ExampleCommand = new Command(OnExampleCommandExecute);
    }

    public string Property
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(PropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData PropertyProperty = RegisterProperty("Property", typeof(string), null);

    public void UpdateProperty(string modifier)
    {
        Property = modifier.ToString();
    }

    public Command ExampleCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnExampleCommandExecute()
    {
        ExecuteCommand();
    }

    protected abstract void ExecuteCommand();

    protected void AddPropertyChange(string propertyName, Type senderType)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => propertyName);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => senderType);
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Then from OpenViewModel I want to send information to MainWindowViewModel.

The OpenViewModel Source code:

```
public class OpenViewModel : CommunicationViewModel
{
    private readonly IMessageService iMessage;
    private readonly IPleaseWaitService iPleaseWait;
    private readonly ILanguageService iLanguage;

    public OpenViewModel(IMessageService iMessageService, IPleaseWaitService iPleaseWaitService, ILanguageService iLanguageService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iMessageService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iPleaseWaitService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iLanguageService);

        iMessage = iMessageService;
        iPleaseWait = iPleaseWaitService;
        iLanguage = iLanguageService;

        ChooseDatabaseForOpen = new Command(HandleChooseDatabaseForOpen);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Databases
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(SettingGenerator.ReadFewSameDatabaseSettings("Databases", "Database", "Value")); }
        set { SetValue(DatabasesProperty, value); }
    }        
    public static readonly PropertyData DatabasesProperty = RegisterProperty("Databases", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), () => new ObservableCollection<string>());

    public Command ChooseDatabaseForOpen { get; private set; }

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await base.InitializeAsync();
        // TODO: subscribe to events here
    }

    protected override async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        // TODO: unsubscribe from events here
        await base.CloseAsync();
    }

    private void HandleChooseDatabaseForOpen()
    {
        iPleaseWait.Show(iLanguage.GetString("PleaseWaitMessage"));
        SettingGenerator.ChangeDatabaseSetting(null, "ActiveDatabase", this.Database);
        iPleaseWait.Hide();
    }

    protected override void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        // InterestedIn does not required any custom logic
    }
}
```

And the MainWindowViewModel

```
[InterestedIn(typeof(OpenViewModel))]
public class MainWindowViewModel : CommunicationViewModel
{
    private const string PATH_TO_CHECKED_IMAGE = @"./../Resources/Images/Icons/Settings/Checked Checkbox.png";
    private const string PATH_TO_UNCHECKED_IMAGE = @"./../Resources/Images/Icons/Settings/Checkbox.png";

    private readonly IUIVisualizerService iUIVisualizer;
    private readonly IPleaseWaitService iPleaseWait;
    private readonly IMessageService iMessage;
    private readonly IOpenFileService iOpenFile;
    private readonly ILanguageService iLanguage;
    private readonly ISplashScreenService iSplashScreen;

    private readonly string settingFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FileConstants.PATH_TO_SETTINGS_FILE;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IUIVisualizerService iUIVisualizerService, IPleaseWaitService iPleaseWaitService, IMessageService iMessageService, IOpenFileService iOpenFileService, ILanguageService iLanguageService, ISplashScreenService iSplashScreenService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iOpenFileService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iUIVisualizerService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iMessageService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iPleaseWaitService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iLanguageService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => iSplashScreenService);

        this.iOpenFile = iOpenFileService;
        this.iUIVisualizer = iUIVisualizerService;
        this.iMessage = iMessageService;
        this.iPleaseWait = iPleaseWaitService;
        this.iLanguage = iLanguageService;
        this.iSplashScreen = iSplashScreenService;

        Minimize = new Command(HandleMinimizeCommand);
        Restore = new Command(HandleRestoreCommand);
        CloseApplication = new Command(HandleCloseApplicationCommand);

        if (SettingGenerator.ReadDatabaseSetting(null, "Update") == "Automatic")
        {
            this.AutoUpgradeCheckbox = PATH_TO_CHECKED_IMAGE;
        }
        else if (SettingGenerator.ReadDatabaseSetting(null, "Update") == "Manual")
        {
            this.AutoUpgradeCheckbox = PATH_TO_UNCHECKED_IMAGE;
        }

        SelectIconForMainMenuItems();

        //this.Property = this.Database;
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(IViewModel viewModel, string propertyName)
    {
        AddPropertyChange(propertyName, viewModel.GetType());
    }

    protected override void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        // InterestedIn does not required any custom logic
    }
}
```

And from xaml

The OpenView

```
<ListView Name="DatabasesListView" MinHeight="150" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}" SelectedItem="{Binding Property}" />
```

The MainWindowView

```
<Label Content="{Binding Property}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 0" FontSize="14" />
```

How can communicate this two view models. In example is working in my case is not working. When I change `Property` everytime is `null`. Is not give me some exception just everytime is null.

**EDIT:** I used two DataWindows, not using UserControls

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation explains](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+communication+styles), there are several ways to communicate between view models:

1. Services
2. InterestedIn (what you are using)
3. MessageMediator

It looks like what you are doing is correct. If you feel it is not working as expected, please provide a repro in the [official tracker](http://catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker).

Comment: I asked and waiting for some answer